# C# changing tab color based on filed value in datagridviiew

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a tablelayoutpanel. On the left is a DataGridView. On the left is tabcontrol with 3 tabs.  What I am trying to do is change the color of the tab headers based on a value in the selected row of the datagrid view on the left.  Each time a new row is selected, any of the tabs can be default color or another color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask To help get better answers, at very least screenshots if not actual code (if AT ALL possible) that shows current vs desired and what you tried already. Without code to improve its very hard to help you, short of directing you to google yet another thing ;)

Comment: you use the row changed event, get the value, and change the tab color accordingly, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected row in DataGridView, you can subscribe to the event `CellClick`.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["here is the column index"].Value.ToString());
}
```

As to set the tab color, you can traverse their `BackColor` property by `foreach` statement.

```
foreach (TabPage tabPage in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    tabPage.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```